# mongoose query result missing field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have just started using `node` with `express` framework and `mongo` as a database.

I created the schema like this :

```
var JsonSchema = new Schema({                                                               
 type: String,                                                                           
 properties: {                                                                           
     OBJECTID: Number,                                                                   
     AREA: Number,                                                                       
     PERIMETER: Number,                                                                  
     ESYE_CODE: Number,                                                                  
     Descriptio: String                                                                  
 },                                                                                      
 geometry: {                                                                             
     type: String,                                                                       
     coordinates: [Number, Number]                                                       
 }                                                                                       
});
```

and then I query :

```
router.get('/mapjson/:OBJECTID', function(req, res) {
 if(req.params.OBJECTID) {
     Json.findOne({OBJECTID: req.params.OBJECTID }, {}, function(err, docs){
         res.json(docs);
 } else {
     console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR HERE!!!");
 }
});
```

But the results I get are missing the `geometry` field.

Sample of results I get :

```
{ 
"_id":"57e43ec60534d33ccc13099b",
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{
    "OBJECTID":212428,
    "AREA":131.001991421,
    "PERIMETER":49.9141344212,
    "ESYE_CODE":147,
    "Descriptio":"Ελληνικά"
    }
 }
```

and what I get when I query the collection from mongo shell  :

```
db.points.findOne({'properties.OBJECTID': 212428})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e43ec60534d33ccc13099b"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
            "OBJECTID" : 212428,
            "AREA" : 131.001991421,
            "PERIMETER" : 49.9141344212,
            "ESYE_CODE" : 147,
            "Descriptio" : "Ελληνικά"
    },
    "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    23.812561006040106,
                    38.093951650544334
            ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The res.json( is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error with copy/paste. I fixed it.

Comment: req.params.OBJECTID, the object that is search has geometry in the database? Only Find to find all can be good for test.

Comment: Yes I can confirm there's a geometry for this OBJECTID. Tried `find()` but still the same result

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for mentioning it. I changed type to {type: String} but nothing has changed to the response.

Comment: @Mes Did you change the definition for both of your `type` fields?

Comment: @JohnnyHK ooops!! I forgot the second field!! I changed it and now its working!! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

In coordinates you can set type as Array:

```
 geometry: {                                                                             
     type: String,                                                                       
     coordinates: Array                                                       
 }
```

Comment: I changed it to `Array` but I'm still getting the same result.